# Running service for android calendar changes?

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentprovider, contentobserver

My goal is to write an app that listens for changes in android calendar. It doesn't seem like there's support for broadcasts in this case, but what's needed is a `ContentObserver`.

If I want a `ContentObserver` to run indefinitely, it requires a thread to keep running when the app is closed (ultimately I want it to start on mobile boot).

Is a service a good solution for this? Or is it bad having a service running all the time? Will it drain a lot of battery, even though all I will be doing is keeping a `ContentObserver` registered?

As far as I can see, my only alternative is to use periodical polling, but I would rather not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It doesn't seem like there's support for broadcasts in this case,

but it does. you must use [ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED) with

```
android:scheme="content"
android:host="com.android.calendar"
```

So a receiver with this intent-filter works:

```
<receiver
   android:name=".CalendarChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:host="com.android.calendar"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Similar way I have a running service for android media image content provider changes. So how to use broadcast receiver in this case using Action_Provider_Changed

Comment: No idea just search @AnkeshkumarJaisansaria